# Doesn't ListView_InsertColumn work while handling WM_INITDIALOG?

Tags: windows, listview, visual-c++

I called **ListView_InsertColumn** to insert some columns to a listview while handling the **WM_INITDIALOG** message, but I couldn't see any columns in the listview, though the return value of **ListView_InsertColumn** was not **-1**.

However, it did work if I called that function while handling a button-clicked message.

Why? If that's the case, how can I initialize the listview?

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it's my oversight. During **WM_INITDIALOG**, I tried to use the global handle variable **gDlg** to get the handle of the listview. But the value of **gDlg** was only assigned by the return value of **CreateDialog**. I didn't know that **WM_INITDIALOG** actually occurs before **CreateDialog** returns;